# XPath statement to get the name of the first element in an NSXMLDocument

Tags: objective-c, xml, xpath, nsxmldocument

I need to get the **name** of the first element in an XML document, e.g. the string "TitleName" of the XML snippet (which is the first line of an XML document):

```
<TitleName Major="1" Minor="0" Revision="1">
```

What `XPath` command (`XPathRootName` in the code snippet below) would I need to specify for this `NSXMLDocument` in order to get the string "TitleName"?

```
NSData *xmlData = [xmlStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSXMLDocument *xmlDocument = [[NSXMLDocument alloc]initWithData:xmlData 
      options:0 error:&error];

NSXMLElement *rootNameXMLElement = [[xmlDocument 
      nodesForXPath:XPathRootName error:&error] lastObject];;
NSString *rootName = rootNameXMLElement.stringValue;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath expression `/*` would match the document element, but it would be simpler just to use the `rootElement` property of `xmlDocument` to get this element directly without using XPath.

Comment: Thank you Ian! Both methods return the full document in my case (below the TitleName). I would need only "TitleName".

Comment: @AlexR once you have a reference to the right node you want its `name` property, not its `stringValue`

Comment: That was exactly my problem! My code works now. Thank you so much, Ian!!